# How would I position JTextFields and JTextArea like this without using a GUI builder?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ncykm5K.png]

How would I position JTextFields and JTextArea like this without using a GUI builder or MiG Layout or something like that, is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `BorderLayout`. Add the scroll pane containing the text area to the `CENTER`. Add the text field to the `PAGE_END`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: I read about that, but can you do something `pixel` specific? E.g.: `300, 300?`

Comment: You should NOT use pixel specific layouts (for too many reasons to list here) and there is absolutely no reason to attempt to do this for this requirement. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is an accepted answer, In this case even a simple BoxLayout with vertical axis `Y_AXIS` should work fine. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

Comment: Not as well, because the BoxLayout will attempt to give each component extra vertical space as the frame is resized. Generally you want your text field to be a fixed height with extra space going to the text area and then the scrollbar will appear/disappear as required.

Comment: makes sense that way. But I think it can be countered by overriding `getMaximumSize()` in JTextField or by simply setting  max size in `setMaximumSize(Dimension d)`.

Comment: Yes you can make it work using a BoxLayout (or a GridBagLayout or a SpringLayout). I was just pointing out that you need to do extra work if you want to use the BoxLayout (or another layout manager). Me, I'm lazy so I try to do as little work as possible :)

Comment: thats called smart camickr :)